# Нумерация и вывод списка

Tags: python, list, список

Пример: я чередую завтраки в порядке: гречка-манка-рис. Нужно составить план на следующие n дней.
Что должно получиться:

```
5 дней
1-гречка
2-манка
3-рис
4-гречка
5-манка
```

вот что выходит у меня, но он каждый продукт прописывает n кол-во раз вместе с нумерацией.

```
n = int(input("кол-во дней:"))
items = ["гречка", "манка", "рис" ]
for i, item in enumerate (items):
    for _ in range (n):
        print(i+1, item)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логически твой алгоритм: взять элемент из списка и n раз вывести.

Нужен другой: совершить n циклов и брать следующий элемент, а если дошли до конца, то начать с первого.

```
items = ["гречка", "манка", "рис" ]
step = 0
for _ in range(n):
  if step == len(items):
    step = 0
  print(items[step])
  step += 1
```

От условия можно избавиться, зная как работает оператор получения остатка от деления `%`.

```
items = ["гречка", "манка", "рис" ]
for i in range(n):
  step = i % len(items)
  print(items[step])
```

Когда i становится равен количеству элементов, то остаток от деления возвращает 0, и так далее. Получается цикличный перебор без условий

Comment: может ещё добавите вариант через очередь из модуля коллекции ?

Comment: Можете добавить как отдельный ответ, я лайкну) Но мне кажется, для решения этой задачи, с меня хватит двух вариантов)

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, всё понял. Еще не разобрался как здесь всё работает, как это  добавить как отдельный ответ?

Comment: Совет @Интик'а про очередь? Это он должен сам сделать